# .htaccess rewrite rule IP check being ignored

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

So, I have the following code in a .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %(REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.456\.789\.000$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^sub\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sub.domain.com/?t=%{REMOTE_ADDR} [R=301,L]
```

I basically want it to not redirect if you're coming from this IP, but it still redirects. I'm sure the IP address that is sees is correct, as I redirect with a query string containing the IP, and it's the same as what I'm checking.

So, am I correct in thinking that this is saying:

Redirect if
REMOTE_ADDR *is not* 123.456.789.000
**AND**
HTTP_HOST *does not* start with 'sub.'

Am I getting mixed up with how it checks more than one condition together?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. If both conditions as met as you described, it redirects.

Comment: So surely when I come from IP 123.456.789.000 I shouldn't get redirected? The issue is coming from this IP should be exempt from the redirect but it still redirects.

Comment: If you're at the subdomain with the correct ip then no, it should not redirect.

Comment: From your Apache logs check what was original URL received and what is IP address as seen by Apache.

Comment: @MattRogowski when you get redirected, what's in the `t=` parameter? Is it the IP in the rewrite condition?

Comment: Yes, so it's seeing the correct IP, but I don't want it to redirect  if visiting from this IP.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution!

I had same problem and your question help me, thanks!

You mistake in this line: `RewriteCond %(REMOTE_ADDR}`

Right will be: `RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR}`

figured brace

Comment: (╯°□°)╯︵ ┻━┻

Sigh.